# Rocket differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Looking for differential equation exercises I have stumbled upon one I thought it was interesting. Here is the exercise:

> A rocket with structural mass $M$ contains fuel with initial mass $m$. It's fired and expels, with sped $v$, $k$ kilograms of gases per second. Ignoring all forces except the weight and assuming the acceleration of gravity is constant, ¿What will be its height and speed when it runs out of fuel?

I looked how to apply differential equations to this context and I stumbled upon [this site](http://exploration.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktpow.html) and many others with essentially the same content. I have learned from there and I perfectly understand what to do and why.

The thing is, every time I follow the steps and try to solve it I get a different result. The textbook says the answer is $y=\frac{C+2x^3}{Cx-4}$, but I don't know exactly what that answer means (How do I know what has the book called x and y?), since it gives a purely mathematical answer with no context.

I get to $\frac{d(m,u)}{dt}=\frac{d(k)v}{dt}$ consistently when I try to solve it, but then it gets confusing (Probably the variable names, I don't know) and when I try to solve it or go further I get everything but the correct answer, or at least nothing remotely similar to what the textbooks says it should be.I even got logarithms mixed in there somehow.

Since it's not a numerical problem I'm sure there is some step I'm doing wrong, but I have no idea which one.

So, the question is, ¿How exactly do I solve this? ¿What could I be doing wrong? I have been trying to solve this every day for a week and I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

What I have tried so far is applying the moment conservation law and then the second newton law, but I have troubles with some of the steps. Some of them 'jump too far' and I'm having troubles seeing what has been done.

Answer (score 1):

Let the total mass of the rocket at any time be $N(t)$, its upward velocity be $w(t)$ and its altitude be $h(t)$.  We have $N(0)=M+m, \frac {dN(t)}{dt}=\frac {dm}{dt}=-k,v(0)=0,h(0)=0, \frac {dw}{dt}=\frac{kv}{N(t)}-g=\frac{kv}{M+m-kt}-g$  Integrate the last to get the upward velocity as a function of $t$, then integrate again to get the altitude.  Burnout is at time $\frac mk$